# How to export a Microsoft Project file (mpp) to tif (tiff) without popup save file dialog?

Tags: .net, printing, export, tiff, ms-project

The customer wanna preview mpp content without open Project Professional.So I decide to convert mpp file to image file.

I already know that the Project Application interface has a method named EditCopyPicture can output to GIF,but when mpp is very large,gif doesnt look very vell.My boss tell me output to tif is a good solution.

I found the "Microsoft Office Document Imaging Writer" can print mpp to tif,but it will popup a dialog to let user select file save path,I'm developing a plugin for Project so I don't want to let user to do this.

I didnt find any method in Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject to set output file path explicitly.The method FilePrint also doesnt have any parameter to set it.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be to use Office automation to print to a postscript printer driver to get a (PostScript) PS file. This could then be converted to PDF using GhostScript so its can be opened in Acrobat Reader, this would work well for the Web.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with word documents using

```
objWdDoc.PrintOut(PrintToFile:=True, OutputFileName:=sDestination & sFileName & ".tif")
```

Maybe something similar works for project.